# Bootstrap modal doesnt show with location.href

Tags: javascript, html, django, twitter-bootstrap

I want the Bootstrap modal to pop up first and I will get some data from it and with that data I want to go a href location.

```js
function callModal(curr){
    var currele = curr.id;
    alert(currele);

    switch (currele){

        case "add_resource":
        {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            window.location.href="add/resource";     
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div>
<a href="#" onClick= "callModal(this)" id = "add_resource" >add resouce</a><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**The issue is : only the href is being called, not the modal**
If I remove the href call , then the modal is getting called fine, but together its not getting called.

** In the Code snippet , you can ignore the undefined href location error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the solution. Just using 2 separate functions would solve it. :) **

```js
<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <h2>Modal Example</h2>

    <!-- Modal -->
    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
      <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
            <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body">
            <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
          </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div>
    <a href="#" onClick="callModal(this)" id="add_resource">add resouce</a><br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

```js
var direction = "Saurabh Adhikary is best";
function callModal(curr){
    
    var currele = curr.id;
    alert(currele);

    switch (currele){

        case "add_resource":
        {
            $("#myModal").modal('show');
            direction ="add/resource";     
            break;
        }
}
}
function printer()
{
alert(direction);
location.href = direction;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Modal Example</h2>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
    
      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p >Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" onClick= printer() class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </div>
  </div>
  
</div>

<div>
<a href="#" onClick= "callModal(this)" id = "add_resource" >add resouce</a><br>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you redirect to the new location just after the modal open and there is no time for you to see it opening. When you redirect to a new location, all of your dom states are refreshed.

Comment: any solution to it ? how to perform both these operations ??

Comment: What kind of data do you want to get from the Modal firstly? That part is unclear to me.

Comment: That will be quite basic , of some user options from drop down menu.
(This part is done & working).

Comment: Do you want to insert remote content inside your modal? or you want to capture input from inside the modal and send that data along to the new URL?